# Why this cloud function takes LONG time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It is a very simple cloud function .It will definitely return something ("successful") then why it is taking more than 60 sec which cause TimeOut error

```
exports.confirmOrder = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { 

    await new Promise((res,rej)=>{

    return true;

    }).then(()=>{

      console.log("llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll");

    }).catch((err)=>{

      console.log(err);

    });

    return "successful";

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callable Cloud Function is done when it returns a response to the caller. If you can't synchronously return a value, you should return a promise the resolves with the value.

Your code doesn't return any response (neither a value nor a promise), so Cloud Functions has no way to know when it's done. In this case it lets it run for as long as possible/configured (60 seconds by default).

This should be a lot closer to what you want:

```
exports.confirmOrder = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { 

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      return true;
    }).then(()=>{
      console.log("llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll");
      resolve();
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
      reject()
    });
});
```

Note that `new Promise()` is quite non-idiomatic in Cloud Functions code, since most libraries/APIs you're calling already return promises. I'm assuming you're just testing how promises work though, given the nature of the code.

Comment: In your code how I can send some data like "successful " string to client .I think returning promise limited to server. If I return json object instead string (Here "successful ") then it will work fine?

Comment: To send a result back to the caller, replace `resolve()` with `resolve("successful")`.

Comment: ok I added your code in my code https://gist.github.com/ak1542/86f886751cb81a3e284def504cb4a957   but it also not work for me